# What is different between SimpleDataObject and ExtensibleDataObject in magento 2

Tags: magento2

Magento has 2 classes

> \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter

and

> \Magento\Framework\Api\SimpleDataObjectConverter

What are the differences and scenario for using them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter` is the converter used to convert classes that extends from `\Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractExtensibleObject`

For deep understand you can check the method toNestedArray() that is implemented in `\Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter` and not in `\Magento\Framework\Api\SimpleDataObjectConverter`

```
public function toNestedArray(
        ExtensibleDataInterface $dataObject,
        $skipAttributes = [],
        $dataObjectType = null
    ) {
        if ($dataObjectType == null) {
            $dataObjectType = get_class($dataObject);
        }
        $dataObjectArray = $this->dataObjectProcessor->buildOutputDataArray($dataObject, $dataObjectType);
        //process custom attributes if present
        if (!empty($dataObjectArray[AbstractExtensibleObject::CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES_KEY])) {
            /** @var AttributeValue[] $customAttributes */
            $customAttributes = $dataObjectArray[AbstractExtensibleObject::CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES_KEY];
            unset($dataObjectArray[AbstractExtensibleObject::CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES_KEY]);
            foreach ($customAttributes as $attributeValue) {
                if (!in_array($attributeValue[AttributeValue::ATTRIBUTE_CODE], $skipAttributes)) {
                    $dataObjectArray[$attributeValue[AttributeValue::ATTRIBUTE_CODE]]
                        = $attributeValue[AttributeValue::VALUE];
                }
            }
        }
        if (!empty($dataObjectArray[ExtensibleDataInterface::EXTENSION_ATTRIBUTES_KEY])) {
            /** @var array $extensionAttributes */
            $extensionAttributes = $dataObjectArray[ExtensibleDataInterface::EXTENSION_ATTRIBUTES_KEY];
            unset($dataObjectArray[ExtensibleDataInterface::EXTENSION_ATTRIBUTES_KEY]);
            foreach ($extensionAttributes as $attributeKey => $attributeValue) {
                if (!in_array($attributeKey, $skipAttributes)) {
                    $dataObjectArray[$attributeKey] = $attributeValue;
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataObjectArray;
    }
```

It gonna convert extras informations into the array (extension_attributes or custom_attributes - check [devdocs for deeply explanation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html))